# Exclude a directory from all ISAPI Rewrite 3 Rules in an HTACCESS file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, isapi, isapi-rewrite

In our .htaccess file, we have a bunch of different rewrite rules that we add on to periodically. Also, on our site, we have a directory that we NEVER want to be rewritten. So, above each rewrite rule, we include a condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{URL} ^(?!/excludeddirectory/.*$)
RewriteRule ...
```

Instead of having to remember to add this RewriteCond any time we write a new RewriteRule that might affect that directory, is there a way to write a single line that overrides all rewrite rules in the file and tells the rewrite engine to ignore this directory no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following rule above all other rules in your config:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/excludeddirectory/
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```